# A command is already in progress .NET and postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am trying to make this call and I cannot go beyond this issue. I've looked on other sites but couldn't find a solution.

I have this API i call that retrieves all the players from database, but since they are not sorted in db i add index when i retrieve them all, I cannot do it any other way. So for each retrieved player i have to make a call also for index to see what position it has based on score. Adding index to db is not an option for several reasons.

```cs
   players = await playerRepo.GetSortedWithFilterDescendingPaginated(page - 1, pageSize, 
                   x => x.Score, 
                   x=> x.FullName.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()));
   
   foreach (var playa in players)
              {
                   var newPlaya = new PlayerDashboardDto()
                   {
                       Index = await playerRepo.GetCount(x => x.Score > playa.Score) + 1,
                       Player = playa
                   };
               
                   listOfPlayers.Add(newPlaya);
               }
```

It builds just as fine but it crashes when I call a method that contains this piece of code. I have found similar issues on the internet but I couldn't solve mine.

This is a piece of error:

```
   Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException (0x80004005): A command is already in progress: 
       SELECT 
       p.nickname, p.full_name, p.level, p.score, p.time
       FROM metacars.player AS p
       WHERE @__ToLower_0 = '' OR strpos(lower(p.full_name), @__ToLower_0) > 0
       ORDER BY p.score DESC 
       LIMIT @__p_2 OFFSET @__p_1
      at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector. <StartUserAction>g__DoStartUserAction|277_0(ConnectorState newState, NpgsqlCommand command,  <>c__DisplayClass277_0& )
      at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState, NpgsqlCommand >command, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean attemptPgCancellation)
      at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, >CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, >CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, >CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: Do you reuse the same connection for concurrent commands (in different threads for example)?

Comment: Please take a look at the formatting of your question. At the moment it is rather unreadable.

Comment: yes i do reuse the same connection in different threads @Ralf

Comment: Then don't do that.

Comment: @Ralf How then should i solve this issue

Comment: Always create a new connection for every command. You don't need to try to optimize here and reuse something. There is a connection pooling implemented already behind the scene that keeps track of "real" connections. For you to implement is create Connection, Commands, Readers etc. as late as possible and destroy them as early as possible. Everything else is handled for you.